# How to include Chart.js in my AngularJS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, chart.js

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm currently working on building an application on Ubuntu. When I'm trying to install Chart.js using `npm install chart.js`, it is throwing the following **error**.

> ```
> npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/karma/node_modules/fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>
> + chart.js@2.9.3
> updated 1 package and audited 19058 packages in 9.013s
>
> 23 packages are looking for funding
>   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities
> ```

**What does this error mean?**

**How do I fix this?**

**Is there any other way to include Chart.js in my project other than the install command?**

Comment: So far, you you didn't get any _errors_, only warnings. The package was installed. Doesn't it work? If so, describe it with more detail.

Comment: As far as I know the package didn't get installed because the installed package would get reflected in the package.json file. But in that file I don't see anything related to chart.js. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are 0 vulnerabilities in your install. what you call error is just `WARN` means warnings, which can be ignored, `Chart.js` has successfully installed. you should be good to go.

If you want to get rid of these warnings, as it says `You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Try npm install `jasmine-core@>=3.5`

Answer (score 0):

npm decided to add a new command: npm fund that will provide more visibility to npm users on what dependencies are actively looking for ways to fund their work.

npm install will also show a single message at the end in order to let user aware that dependencies are looking for funding, it looks like this:

```
$ npm install
13 packages are looking for funding.
run `npm fund` for details.
```

Running npm fund  will open the url listed for that given package right in your browser.

**npm funding does not mean that the package is not installed , your package is successfully installed.**

[please check this for more information](https://dev.to/ruyadorno/npm-6-13-0-7f3)

Answer (score 0):

you didnt get any errors  only warnings, you can ignore them.
first of all you can download manually from https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js
but you already installed them  from npm so try to include it in your project

when you load your angular module dont forget to use

```
angular.module('myModule', ['chart.js']);
```

let us know if you were  able to use it , best of luck !

Comment: Yes I tried it and the charts are getting displayed. Thanks a lot for your help :D

Comment: glad to know :) .